# Show Custom Menu On Menu Button Click

Tags: android

I have created an Activity that will behave like a popup menu is actually just a list of Menu Items. I then set the theme of the activity on my manifest to "Dialog" to get the popup effect. Now I need this activity to show when the Menu button is pressed on the device. I tried using onCreateOptionsMenu, then passing my Activity XML to the Inflater like so:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, menu);

    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

"popup_menu" is the XML for my Activity. But this didnt work. Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should start your activity there. I can tell you more if I see the code for your activity

Comment: Dude! Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Start the activity as normal with an Intent, then return true.

Comment: But now I have another problem. The Activity/Menu shows once. As in, once I dismiss it with the Back Button, it cannot be loaded again..

Comment: Thank You Gabi, that helped a lot. Problem Solved.